# OpenGL intersection between vector and face

Tags: c++11, math, linear-algebra

I have a terrain and an object which should moves over the terrain so I made a function that can detect which face is the origin of the object locate above so I should set the Y of the object with the accurate height of the intersection point between the vector from the object origin perpendicular with the face, I have the three vertices of the face so I can calculate its normal and its origin and maximum and minimum pointes (bounded box).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifhIL.png)

Edit:
the question in another form:
if I know x and z of a point over a triangle in the 3D space how can I know it y if it is a point in the triangle?

Comment: Perform a standard ray-triangle intersection?

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer and not in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[the Möller–Trumbore intersection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6ller%E2%80%93Trumbore_intersection_algorithm)

this is the implementation:

```
bool EngineItem::checkIntersection(glm::vec3& rayOrigin, glm::vec3& rayVector, Face& face, glm::vec3& point) {
    const float EPSILON = 0.0000001;
    glm::vec3 vertex0 = face.v1;
    glm::vec3 vertex1 = face.v2;
    glm::vec3 vertex2 = face.v3;
    glm::vec3 edge1, edge2, h, s, q;
    float a, f, u, v;
    edge1 = vertex1 - vertex0;
    edge2 = vertex2 - vertex0;
    h = glm::cross(rayVector, edge2);
    a = glm::dot(edge1, h);
    if (a > -EPSILON && a < EPSILON)
        return false;
    f = 1 / a;
    s = rayOrigin - vertex0;
    u = f * glm::dot(s, h);
    if (u < 0.0 || u > 1.0)
        return false;
    q = glm::cross(s, edge1);
    v = f * glm::dot(rayVector, q);
    if (v < 0.0 || u + v > 1.0)
        return false;
    float t = f * glm::dot(edge2, q);
    if (t > EPSILON) {
        glm::vec3 plus = glm::normalize(rayVector) * (t * glm::length(rayVector));
        point = rayOrigin + plus;
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}
```